# Did Snape know that James Potter had a cloak of invisibilty?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Sorcerer's Stone, when Snape was roughing up Prof. Quirrell in the hallway, Snape noticed that something was nearby (Harry under the cloak of invisibility).

I guess Snape heard Harry breathing. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)
I have two questions: did Snape know about the cloak since James probably used it when they were at school?
And did Snape know it was Harry under the cloak?

Comment: I don’t think this is ever established in the canon, but I would guess not. Otherwise the finger of blame points more clearly at Harry for certain things (e.g. ingredients for Polyjuice disappearing from his stores in second year). I always thought that it was Snape hearing Harry’s breathing, although I don’t think it’s verified anywhere.

Comment: @AlexChan: however it is established that Snape must have learnt about the cloak for sure by the time of GOF (`'Potter!' Snape snarled, and he actually turned his head and stared right at the place where Harry was, as though he could suddenly see him. 'That egg is Potter's egg. That piece of parchment belongs to Potter. I have seen it before, I recognise it! Potter is here!` **`Potter, in his Invisibility Cloak!'`**), probably earlier.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: indeed.  In fact, I think it's when Prof. Snape finds Harry's invisibility cloak near the end of Prisoner when he learns it's Harry's.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: true. In fact, doesn’t Snape use it to sneak into the Shrieking Shack? So he might have guessed that James owned the cloak, but I don’t think he knew James had a cloak *when they were both at school*. Which is subtlely different and I should probably have clarified.

Comment: But doesn't it defeat the purpose of having a Deathly Hollow that makes you undetectable if the Head of Hogswarts can look right at you? Knowledge doesn't equal discovery.

Comment: @Jersey - It doesn't make you undetectable. People under the cloak can still be seen if the cloak doesn't cover them completely (See apparating to 13 Grimmaud), footprints still appear in snow, you can be bumped into, you do appear on the Marauder's Map, etc. The cloak itself is impervious to harm, and makes you truly invisible to the eye, but that is as far as it goes.

Answer (score 7):

Snape likely heard Harry's breathing (as Harry was no doubt nervous about being caught and thus breathing hard); any magical method alerting him to detection would have no doubt provoked him to drop Quirrell and search for the observer. He simply thought he heard breathing, looked around, Harry held his breath, and then Snape decided he was imagining things.

As to whether Snape was aware that James had an invisibility cloak prior to Harry's birth, I doubt it. It seems to be implied in the backstory that James kept his ownership of the cloak relatively quiet (as did historical users of the cloak Hallow), and that only his closest friends and Dumbledore knew of it. (This is just supposition based on the backstory however. It's never explicitly stated that he hid it from others, but ostensibly he would not advertise it, particularly to Snape.)

It seems that Dumbledore respected the tradition of being discreet in regards to the cloak, as it seems that he did not alert the teachers of Hogwarts (or even fellow order member Prof. McGonagall) to Harry's possession of it when he first gave it to Harry. I suspect that he did so in order to allow Harry to explore freely; we see in Snape's memories in Deathly Hallows that Dumbledore manipulated Harry's childhood to encourage the development of various character traits (such as placing him with the Dursleys in order to humble him) that would help him in what he eventually would have to do. I think it can be safely assumed that Snape was not aware of Harry's cloak in the Sorcerer's Stone, as it is likely he would have cast Homenum Revelio (which has been established to work against the cloak, which is a bit of an author goof) when he heard Harry's breathing while he interrogated Quirrell.

However it seems that Dumbledore eventually disclosed the cloak to Snape and possibly other teachers, as Snape knew Harry was in possession of the cloak in Prisoner of Azkaban, when Malfoy reported the apparent apparition of Harry's floating head outside the Shrieking Shack, which Snape immediately understood to be Harry using his cloak to sneak into the village. He again spoke of Harry's cloak in The Goblet of Fire when he correctly suspected the egg Moody found on the Grand Staircase was Harry's, and that Harry was probably there observing them from under it.

Comment: "placing him with the Dursleys in order to _humble_ him" You have anything to support that? My recollection is that Harry was with the Dursleys because he needed to be with relatives for the protection around him to work.

Answer (score 2):

I do believe it was the breathing Snape heard, or he could have done the same as Dumbledore in Chamber of Secrets by using Homenum Revelio (as stated by Rowling). Did he know James had a cloak? I don't think it can be answered in canon; there's no indication in the books that I can remember, nor find after a flick through now. Furthermore I can't find anything on any Q and A's by Rowling or on Pottermore.

He could have simply guessed it was Harry, like Dumbledore did in CoS, or he could have used legilimency (though I cannot recall if the target always feels it).

If he knew it was Harry he most likely would have told Dumbledore, in complaint of his arrogance. He said nothing incredibly incriminating of Quirrell at the time, so he wasn't telling Harry anything really, and taking care of Quirrell was more important than telling off a first year — Dumbledore himself told Snape he suspects Quirrell and as far as I remember told Snape to keep an eye on him, as can be read in the Prince's Tale chapter of Deathly Hallows.